# what is an ingress controller and how do I create it?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Good morning guys, so I took down a staging environment for a product on GCP and ran the deployment scripts again, the backend and frontend service have been setup. I have an ingress resource and a load balancer up, however, the service is not running. A look at the production app revealed there was something like an nginx-ingress-controller. I really don't understand all these and how it was created. Can someone help me understand because I have not seen anything online that makes it clear for me. Am I missing something?

loadBalancer: https://gist.github.com/davidshare/5a571e56febe7dacd580282b373f3095
Ingress Resource: https://gist.github.com/davidshare/d0f53912bc7da8310ec3d64f1c8a44f1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ingress** allows access to your Kubernetes services from outside the Kubernetes cluster. There are different kubernetes aka K8 resources alternatively you can use like (Node Port / Loadbalancer) which you can use to expose.

Ingress is independent resource to your service , you can specify **routing rules declaratively**, so each url with some context can be mapped to different services.
This makes it decoupled and isolated from the services you want to expose.

So to work ingress it needs an Ingress Controller for your cluster.

Like deployment resource in K8, ingress can be created simply by

```
kubectl create -f ingress.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to implement [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) in order to apply [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resource, as described in @Shubhu answer. Ingress controller, as an edge router, applies specific logical structure with aim to route external traffic to your Kubernetes cluster underlying services via basic pattern routing rules defined in `Ingress` resource.

If you select [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) then it might be useful to proceed with installation [guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) approaching some specific [prerequisites](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#provider-specific-steps) based on cloud provider environment. In order to simplify Nginx Ingress controller installation procedure it is also possible to use [Helm](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#installing-helm) package manager and install appropriate [stable/nginx-ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#using-helm) Helm chart.